# Assembly: troubles with my linear search code

Tags: assembly, x86, linear-search

For an assignment I have to finish the code for a program that uses a loop to compare each array element to a target value that's provided through user input. So for example, when the program asks me to type a number and I type the number 6, it should give me the sixth number in this list. `'7','3','2','1','0','5','6','4','8','9'`

I typed what the comments told me to type but I keep getting this error when I try to compile it.

```
main.o: In function `getNextElement':
main.asm:(.text+0x92): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against '.data'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;    MACRO DEFINITIONS   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; A macro with two parameters
; Implements the write system call
    %macro writestring 2
        mov eax, 4  ;sys_write system call number
        mov ebx, 1  ;file descriptor std_out
        mov ecx, %1 ;message to write from parameter 1
        mov edx, %2 ;message length from parameter 2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro
; A macro with two parameters
; Implements the sys_read call
    %macro read_string 2
        mov eax, 3  ;sys_write system call number
        mov ebx, 2  ;file descriptor std_in
        mov ecx, %1 ;variable/array to hold data, pass by reference in param 1
        mov edx, %2 ;number of bytes to read passed by value in param 2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;    DATA SEGMENT    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
section .data
msg1 db 'Here are the elements: '
lenmsg1 equ $-msg1
msg2 db 'Enter a number to search for: '
lenmsg2 equ $-msg2
msg3 db 'The target value was found at index '
lenmsg3 equ $-msg3
msg4 db 'The target value was NOT found...',0x0a, 0x0d
lenmsg4 equ $-msg4
asciinums db '7','3','2','1','0','5','6','4','8','9'
lenasciinums equ $-asciinums
crlf db 0x0d, 0x0a
lencrlf equ $ - crlf                
target db 0x00
targetlocation db 0x30

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    writestring msg1, lenmsg1
    writestring asciinums, lenasciinums
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
    writestring msg2, lenmsg2
    read_string target, 1
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
    mov eax, asciinums  ;eax holds base address
    mov ecx, 0          ;ecx is index register
getNextElement:
    mov [eax+ecx], al   ;copy value from asciinums into an 8-bit register
    cmp al, target      ;compare the 8-bit register to target value
    je  targetlocation  ;jump if equal to the found label
    inc ecx             ;increment index register
    cmp ecx, 10         ;compare index register to decimal 10
    jne getNextElement  ;if index register not equal to 10 go to getNextElement

    writestring msg4, lenmsg4
    jmp terminate
found:
    add [targetlocation], ecx
    writestring msg3, lenmsg3
    writestring targetlocation, 1
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
terminate:
    mov eax, 1          ;terminate program
    int 0x80
```

I also know that the problem is from this section of the code.

```
    mov eax, asciinums  ;eax holds base address
    mov ecx, 0          ;ecx is index register
getNextElement:
    mov [eax+ecx], al   ;copy value from asciinums into an 8-bit register
    cmp al, target      ;compare the 8-bit register to target value
    je  targetlocation  ;jump if equal to the found label
    inc ecx             ;increment index register
    cmp ecx, 10         ;compare index register to decimal 10
    jne getNextElement  ;if index register not equal to 10 go to getNextElement
```

This is the website I used to compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php

Comment: `cmp al, target` compares the address of target with _AL_. You want to compare what is at `target` so it should be `cmp al, [target]`. This error causes the linker error you are getting. As well I don't think you meant `je  targetlocation` (that is a label in the data section). Maybe you meant `je  found`? (which is what the comment suggests)

Comment: @MichaelPetch It works but originally when I changed target location to "je found," the output told me "Target value was not found." Changed it to "jmp found" but that just makes it say "Target value was found at index 0." Any ideas how to fix this? I tried different jump fucntions but they don't give me what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're writing code for x86 architecture the problem is `je` instruction in `getNextElement`. `je` instruction is a short jump, it expects relative address as a parameter only and it can't be used to make indirect jumps. Here you can look at the difference between `je` and `jmp` instructions:

http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html

http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html

Added:

`mov [eax+ecx], al   ;copy value from asciinums into an 8-bit register`

Here you're moving `al` into memory and comment says the opposite. Fix it, use `je found` and try again.

Added:

And another one:
`mov [eax+ecx], al   ;copy value from asciinums into an 8-bit register`
here you're ruining `eax` register by loading data into `al`. On the next loop you'll fetch garbage from memory.

Checked, after fixing all mentioned mistakes it works perfectly.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;    MACRO DEFINITIONS   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; A macro with two parameters
; Implements the write system call
    %macro writestring 2
        mov eax, 4  ;sys_write system call number
        mov ebx, 1  ;file descriptor std_out
        mov ecx, %1 ;message to write from parameter 1
        mov edx, %2 ;message length from parameter 2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro
; A macro with two parameters
; Implements the sys_read call
    %macro read_string 2
        mov eax, 3  ;sys_write system call number
        mov ebx, 2  ;file descriptor std_in
        mov ecx, %1 ;variable/array to hold data, pass by reference in param 1
        mov edx, %2 ;number of bytes to read passed by value in param 2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;    DATA SEGMENT    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
section .data
msg1 db 'Here are the elements: '
lenmsg1 equ $-msg1
msg2 db 'Enter a number to search for: '
lenmsg2 equ $-msg2
msg3 db 'The target value was found at index '
lenmsg3 equ $-msg3
msg4 db 'The target value was NOT found...',0x0a, 0x0d
lenmsg4 equ $-msg4
asciinums db '7','3','2','1','0','5','6','4','8','9'
lenasciinums equ $-asciinums
crlf db 0x0d, 0x0a
lencrlf equ $ - crlf                
target db 0x00
targetlocation db 0x30

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    writestring msg1, lenmsg1
    writestring asciinums, lenasciinums
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
    writestring msg2, lenmsg2
    read_string target, 1
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
    mov eax, asciinums  ;eax holds base address
    mov ecx, 0          ;ecx is index register
getNextElement:
    mov bl, [eax+ecx]   ;copy value from asciinums into an 8-bit register
    cmp bl, [target]    ;compare the 8-bit register to target value
    je  found           ;jump if equal to the found label
    inc ecx             ;increment index register
    cmp ecx, 10         ;compare index register to decimal 10
    jne getNextElement  ;if index register not equal to 10 go to getNextElement

    writestring msg4, lenmsg4
    jmp terminate
found:
    add [targetlocation], ecx
    writestring msg3, lenmsg3
    writestring targetlocation, 1
    writestring crlf, lencrlf
terminate:
    mov eax, 1          ;terminate program
    int 0x80
```

Comment: yes, and don't forget to up vote please, if comment was helpful.